# Variable in variable expansion

Tags: shell, variable, variable-substitution

I want to evaluate a variable, whose name will need to dynamically evaluate another varuiable, i.e. the var `ENVIRONMENT` can be either `prod`, `stg`, or `test`, so I have 3 urls:

```
URL_PROD=https://myproduction.com
URL_STG=https://mystaging.com
URL_TEST=https://mytest.com
```

so I want to retrieve say the value of `URL_STG`.

The following does not work

```
echo $"URL_${ENVIRONMENT^^}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the associative arrays' related answer proposed by @Kusalananda I also came up with this:

```
ENDPOINT=URL_${ENVIRONMENT^^}
MY_URL="${!ENDPOINT}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a recent `bash` or `ksh93`, create an associative array to hold the URLs:

```
URL=( [prod]=https://myproduction.com
      [stg]=https://mystaging.com
      [test]=https://mytest.com )

url_type=test

echo "${URL[$url_type]}"
```

This will output the testing URL.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is:

```
eval echo \$URL_${ENVIRONMENT^^}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the value of `$ENVIRONMENT` has to be sanitized first.  If the value is, for example, `test;>file`, your code will create a file called `FILE` in the current directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda - That's a theoretical that isn't relevant to the questioner's use-case. He's (seems to be) processing selecting from a list of URLs.

Comment: That's absolutely true. If one has full control over the contents of the strings that one runs `eval` over, then there is no problem.